# Object has no method use

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to follow [this](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2012/07/13/JavaScript-Toddler-Game-Part-1-Hosting-a-cocos2D-app-in-Nodejs.aspx) tutorial, on hosting Cocos2d in NodeJS, but I'm getting this error message:

```
Object #<Server> has no method 'use'
    at Object.<anonymous>
```

in this line:

```
server.use('/Art', express.static(__dirname + '/Art') );
```

This is my code:

```
var express = require('express'),
    http = require('http');

var app = express();
app.use(express.bodyParser());
var server = http.createServer(app);

server.use('/Art', express.static(__dirname + '/Art') );
server.use('/Platform', express.static(__dirname + '/Platform') );
server.use('/Sounds', express.static(__dirname + '/Sounds') );
server.use('/Src', express.static(__dirname + '/Src') );

server.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.sendfile('index.html');
    console.log('Sent index.html');
});

server.get('/api/hello', function(req,res){
   res.send('Hello Cruel World');
});
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you follow the tutorial very closely. You are using `var server = http.createServer(app);`, but the tutorial uses `server = express.createServer();`. However, the tutorial is two(!) years old, so you might be better off reading the express tutorial directly: http://expressjs.com/guide.html#intro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message tells you what happened: the variable `server` refers to a web server object of Node, not express application. so your code should be corrected to:

```
app.use('/Art', express.static(__dirname + '/Art') );
app.use('/Platform', express.static(__dirname + '/Platform') );
app.use('/Sounds', express.static(__dirname + '/Sounds') );
app.use('/Src', express.static(__dirname + '/Src') );

app.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.sendfile('index.html');
    console.log('Sent index.html');
});

app.get('/api/hello', function(req,res){
    res.send('Hello Cruel World');
});

http.createServer(app).listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```